# How to check if user exists in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Here is it I add value about user.

```
val user = hashMapOf(
                USER_CONVERSATIONS to arrayListOf(""),
                USER_EMAIL_COLUMN to personEmail,
                USER_NAME_COLUMN to personName,
                USER_PHOTO_URL_COLUMN to personPhoto.toString(),
                USER_ID_COLUMN to personId
            )
 db.collection("users").add(user)
```

Which rule do I need to put inside Cloud Filestore or checking inside app?

Here is it my structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wG2DB.jpg

**Thank you for extended answer!**

I would like to do not register my account with new id, and check this in app, answer was given, thank you!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AZlYBBpj2jY check this tutorial

Comment: If you are asking about security rules, you will have to figure out for yourself the permissions required for this document, and any constraints on new data.  There's not enough information here to know what you really need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can request to know if that document exists before inserting it. You can use something like this.

```
firestore.collection("users").whereEqualTo("id", YOUR_USER_ID)
.limit(1).get()
.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                      if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // You can check here if document exist.
                        // It will be empty if it doesnt.
                        boolean isEmpty = task.getResult().isEmpty();
                      }
                    }
                });
```